# DataAdapter.Fill() method

Tags: c#, winforms

Sorry if my question is basic.
For data adapter.fill method there is 5 overload method. I would like to know what is difference between these second overload and third overload and when we use each of them , for example in second overload without  defining  data set it can fill directly data table. I like to know how is possible without defining data set , filling data table.

[second overload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f884C.png)

[third overload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao4Zs.png)

Comment: I think MSDN will have the asnwer for you: [DataAdapter.Fill Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Dataset can holds multiple Datatable so if you want to fill a datatable included on the dataset you need to specify the name of the Datatable on the Dataset

Comment: You can fill a DataTable directly without using a DataSet.  A DS is handy when you need to work with several tables at once, but is not required.  Consulting MSDN for all the fun details means almost never having to ask a basic question

Comment: when fill a DataTable directly without using a DataSet , DataSet automatically will be made? or DataTable filling happen without having DataSet.

Comment: datasets are not required.  it is just a nice container to store multiple data tables

Answer (score 0):

a dt can contains more than one tabe with the name property you can set witch tabe should be taken